# How to match string starting from multiple characters (can be nested) via regex?

Tags: regex

Im trying to make regex to get domain from different kinds of url.

Im using regex, that works properly either with links w/o @ in domain part, e.g:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
https://regexr.com/
```

`/(?<=(\/\/))[^\n|\/|:]+/g`
For links with @ (e.g. `http://regex@regex.com`) works with replasing `\/\/` to `\@`:`/(?<=(@))[^\n|\/|:]+/g`

But when im trying to make regex to match both of these cases and making
`/(?<=((\/\/)|(\@)))[^\n|\/|:]+/g`
it dosen't work.

Comment: It is very complicated to express the `uri` grammar in a regex. If you need this for a specific language, maybe there is already a build in uri parser.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the string `://`,(Positive Look Behind) if it comes in the string means it is domain and you need to capture everything after that. Whether it has `@` or not.

**Case 1**
Capture the whole string after `://`

**Regex:**
`(?<=\:\/\/).*`

**Explanation:**

`Positive Lookbehind (?<=\:\/\/)`
`Assert that the Regex below matches`
`\: matches the character : literally (case sensitive)`
`\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)`
`\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)`
`.* matches any character (except for line terminators)`
`* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)`

**Example**
https://regex101.com/r/jsqqw8/1/

**Case 2**
Capture just the domain after `://`

**Regex:**
`(?<=:\/\/)[^\n|\/|:]+`

**Explanation:**
`Positive Lookbehind (?<=:\/\/)`
`Assert that the Regex below matches`
`: matches the character : literally (case sensitive)`
`\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)`
`\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)`
`Match a single character not present in the list below [^\n|\/|:]+`
`+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)`
`\n matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)`
`| matches the character | literally (case sensitive)`
`\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)`
`|: matches a single character in the list |: (case sensitive)`

**Case 3:**
Capture domain after `://` if there is not `@` in the text and if `@` present in the text, capture text after that.

**Regex:**
`(?!:\/\/)(?:[A-z]+\.)*[A-z][A-z]+\.[A-z]{2,}`

**Explanation:**

```
    Negative Lookahead (?!:\/\/)
Assert that the Regex below does not match
: matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
Non-capturing group (?:[A-z]+\.)*
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Match a single character present in the list below [A-z]+
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
A-z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
Match a single character present in the list below [A-z]
A-z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
Match a single character present in the list below [A-z]+
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
A-z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
Match a single character present in the list below [A-z]{2,}
{2,} Quantifier — Matches between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
A-z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
```

**Example:**
https://regex101.com/r/jsqqw8/4

Comment: If domain contains @, i need a part of the string after @, not ://

Comment: Added case 3 for that solution.

Comment: Oh, thanks! But this dont parse domain naimes with more than one dot. For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history

Comment: Updated case 3 with your reqt.